# Does .NET 3.5 installer include 3.0 SP2?

Tags: .net, installation

We're trying to track down some .Net assembly dependency problems.

On Windows XP, does the .Net 3.5 installer include 3.0 SP2 automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET 3.5 contains .NET 3.0 SP1

.NET 3.5 SP1 contains .NET 3.0 SP2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I believe that Microsoft is building on top of each version of .NET. This leads me to *believe* the answer to your question is '**Yes**'. Hopefully someone can confirm this.